# Issue with OpenStreetMap administration area rendering

Tags: sql-server, maps, geospatial, openstreetmap

I imported latest OpenStreetMap data to local SQLServer db and generated "outer" shape for some administration area. Original area shape is available here:
http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2658573

What I received is below:

[image]

What I did is I took "outer" way definitions for this shape (mentioned above) in the order defined in the db and constructed POLYGON definition from points belonging to all the ways in the order defined in OpenStreetMap db.

To import data to SQLServer db I used OsmSharp.core nuget package.
The orientation of shape data is clockwise as per info on this page(see Naming and Orientation section)):
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Talk:Relation:multipolygon

My questions are:

Does anybody know why taking direct definitions for "ways"/lines describing some area shape doesn't work as it should?
Should I reject some points from line/way definitions?
Maybe I just missed something else...

**Edit 1:**
I did quick query to verify info from **scai** and it looks promising:

[image]

NodeNr column shows which point on the way/line definition I should take as the start/endpoint for polygon definition. WayNr shows which consecutive way shares point with which one.

**Edit 2:**
I tested data related to way definitions already and it looks the main issue is with order of nodes in the way definitions only. All the tested ways used all the nodes belonging to them (no any redundant points were there in case the way could cross some other way in the middle of that way).
Some sample data:

[image]

The definition of the way with nr 42 (WayNr = 42) shows that start point of this line (continuation of the way nr 41) is on position 44. It means point/node 44 in the definition of the way 42 has the same gps/coordinates as point on position 30 in the definition of way nr 41.

After taking such "reverted" lines in the correct order I received the shape shown below:

[image]

After adding an inner area (exclusion) it looks finally as the original one shape:

[image]

The other issue with OpenStreetMap data is it uses right-hand rule to define outer-ring of the shape (clockwise instead of counter-clockwise) so in case of SQLServer we have to use ReorientObject() method on Geography instance. To detect orientation of the shape you can use EnvelopeAngle() method on Geography object for instance.

**Edit 3:**
I received an answer on OSM [forum](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/51019/does-order-of-ways-on-relation-members-is-random) the order of ways on relation members doesn't matter (we can't rely on it) so ways have to be reordered before any further processing yet...

Comment: Based on the link to the shape in OpenStreetMap and what you've posted as coming from your SQL database, it looks right to me. What problem are you having?

Comment: The shape of area differs in a few places (for instance south-west part of it). It looks mu polygon has to many points and I don't know why yet...

Comment: Follow-up questions at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202936/order-of-ways-in-openstreetmap-relation-data-relation-members and https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/51019/does-order-of-ways-on-relation-members-is-random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already various similar questions here at stackoverflow and at gis.stackexchange.com.

Relations don't necessarily contain the ways in the correct order. Thus it will be necessary to order the ways yourself. Take a look at the ID of the last node of a way and search for the way who has the same ID for its start node. If you do this for all ways then the resulting geometry should be fine.

Comment: Thanks scai for the info! To be honest I didn't know yet that such subdomain related to gis exists on SO :)

Comment: your assumption is I should take the last one point from the current way/line and look for the same node id on the next one way. Does it mean I should "link" such generic way all the lines (looking for common points on ways/lines to link ways through them)?
I will look for the answer on gis.SO mentioned by you also :)

Comment: Yes. Consecutive ways will share the same node ID as their end/start. If the multipolygon relation is not broken then there will be only one other way matching this node ID. Continue doing this until having consumed all ways which should automatically lead you to the starting node ID of the first consumed way.

Comment: I added more info after reviewing some data as scai suggested.  
If it's source of the problem I mark question as resolved. Thanks scai for the info :)

Comment: scai, I see order of line points is unpredictable also. Some lines are defined from top to bottom when others from bottom to top. It means I have to detect direction of points to link together also (when NodeNr linking with previous line is higher then NodeNr linking with next one line it means I have to revert order of points defined for such line). Am I right? Strange ...

Comment: I have no idea how OSM data in a database is organized. In [OSM XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) each way will reference all of its nodes in the correct order via `<nd>` elements. The order of `<node>` elements in the XML file is irrelevant. I guess something similar will apply to your database.

Comment: I imported data from file using protocol buffer format. The order of ways defining a relation and order on nodes defining a way have been preserved.

Comment: I removed my answer and left updates on question only (sections marked "Edit x")